# white background with checkbox in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a problem with my checkboxes in chrome. A white background appears behind the checkbox.
This background does not appear in firefix or IE.

[image: checkbox]

How could I fix this please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code please.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own images checked - unchecked and create your custom checkbox in order to be sure that it will be displayed properly in any browser.